# How to properly manage routes with react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've had a problem with redirecting to page via react routing. I want all my private paths to start with `/client/:id` and then add another part to this path when I'clicking onto dashboard menu. Finall path should be something like this: `/client/:id/home`.

So, i start to coding and change my object handling all paths like this:

```
export const routes = {
    home: "/client/:id/home"
}
```

and handling componenet object like this:

```
export const routing = [
    { path: routes.home, component: Home }
]
```

all of this i use in my App.tsx like below:

```
{routing.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
   <Route key={i} path={path} component={component} />
))}
```

And right now I've got a problem. After redirecting to `home` with using `react-router-dom` history like below:

```
const history = useHistory();
history.push(`/client/${id}/home`)
```

router redirect me onto 404 page :(

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where are you doing any redirect (REPLACE)? Where and how are you rendering your routes? Where are you trying to redirect from? Please update question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question. For routing the basic principle is same in case of React, Angular, Vue. Using typescript or JavaScript.
When navigating we do not need to useHistory and push history in it.
You can use nested routing here and achieve the same.
export const routes = {
home: "/client/:id/home"
}
Please find attached example.

```
[https://codepen.io/shwetas7/pen/rNGRNdW][1]
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/shwetas7/pen/rNGRNdW

Comment: It not help me in any way :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with the functionality that you need.
You have to use `history.go();` after `history.push` to reload the page.

```
/*
Question: How to properly manage routes with react-router-dom?
Url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730898/how-to-properly-manage-routes-with-react-router-dom/70731195#70731195
 */

import { Redirect, Route, Router, Switch, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

function Route2({ history, match }) {
  // id = 1
  // const { id } = match.params;
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <div>Route 2</div>
      <button onClick={() => {
        history.push("/");
        history.go();
      }}> navigate to Route 1</button>
    </>
  );
}

function Question4() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/client/:id/home"
            exact
            render={(props) => <Route2 {...props} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/"
            render={({ history }) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <div>Route 1</div>
                  <button onClick={() => {
                    // history.push("/client/1/home");
                    // history.go();
                    window.location.href = '/client/1/home'
                  }}> navigate to Home</button>
                </>
              )
            }}
          />
          <Redirect path="/" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default Question4;
```

I hope I've helped you

Comment: Hmm it helped, but instead of this i'm using `window.location.href = `/client/${id}/home``, but right now, I don't know why but `useParams` return me undefined when i want to get `id` from path

Comment: know you maybe why?

Comment: I have updated the my answer. Now, it is using "window.location.href" and useParams.
I can't tell you what's the error without checking your code. But you can compare my code with yours to know why is happening.
I hope I've helped you